# Using Get-MgUser to find users managers UPN

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to convert all AzureAD cmdlets to Graph cmdlets instead.

We have a script that fetches all accounts and find their managers UPN.

```
$allUsers = Get-MgUser -all -select SignInActivity -filter "Usertype eq 'Member'"

foreach ($user in $allUsers){
$mgr = Get-AzureADUserManager -objectId $user.Id

if ($mgr){
$user | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -Name Manager -Value $mgr.userPrincipalName -force
}

else {
$user | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -Name Manager -Value "NULL" -force
```

What I've got so far, which gives me nothing what I can see, is:

```
$allUsers = get-mguser -all -filter "Usertype eq 'Member'"

foreach ($user in $allUsers){

$mgr = get-mguser -userId $user.Id -expandProperty Manager

if ($user.Manager) {
$mgrUPN = $mgr.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName
$user | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -Name Manager -Value $managerUPN -Force
}

else {
$user | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -Name Manager -Value "NULL" -Force
}

}
```

I was hoping this would return the UPN of the manager, but it gives no result.

If I do it "manually" with the line below it works.
`Get-MgUser -UserId XX -ExpandProperty Manager | Select @{Name = 'Manager'; Expression {$_.Manager.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName}}`

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you against using `Add-Member` every time, it's much better to just re-create the object with `Select-Object`. There is also no need at all to query all users first:

```bash
$allUsers = Get-MgUser -All -Filter "Usertype eq 'Member'"
```

And then querying them again inside your loop:

```bash
$mgr = Get-MgUser -UserId $user.Id -ExpandProperty Manager
```

All of it can be simply reduced to this:

```bash
Get-MgUser -Filter "UserType eq 'Member'" -ExpandProperty Manager -All |
    Select-Object @(
        # You can include more properties of interest here
        'DisplayName'
        'Mail'
        'UserPrincipalName'
        @{ 
            Name       = 'Manager'
            Expression = {
                if($manager = $_.Manager.AdditionalProperties['userPrincipalName']) {
                    return $manager
                }
                'NULL'
            }
        }
    )
```

If you want to exclude any user not having the `manager` attribute set, unfortunately the filtering has to be done on PowerShell side, `manager ne null` is not valid in the filter to Users Graph API.

```bash
Get-MgUser -Filter "UserType eq 'Member'" -ExpandProperty Manager -All |
    Where-Object { $_.Manager.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName } |
    Select-Object @(
        # You can include more properties of interest here
        'DisplayName'
        'Mail'
        'UserPrincipalName'
        @{
            Name       = 'Manager'
            Expression = $_.Manager.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName
        }
    )
```

Comment: This also returns NULL for every user without a manager. If I remove 'NULL' from the script it returns an empty line instead for those users. How can I fix it so only users with a manager shows in the list?

Comment: @LaserWhale unfortunately `manager` is not a property you can filter with your query to Azure so what you can do is filter with PowerShell, see the update to my answer